# Apache Flink EMR

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to create an EMR cluster for Apache Flink and the first option I can choose looks like this:

[image]

The Apache Flink is not mentioned in any of the options. Which one should I choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the CLI:

```
aws emr create-cluster --name "Cluster with Flink" --release-label emr-5.14.0 \
--applications Name=Flink --ec2-attributes KeyName=myKey \
--instance-type m4.large --instance-count 3 --use-default-roles
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hidden away in the UI. You need to click "go to advanced options". Then you can select Flink.

[image]